# xjc, generate java classes from xsd (using URL) in gradle 7.2

Tags: gradle, xsd, xjc

I use plugin com.github.bjornvester.xjc to generate java classes from xsd:

```
xjc {
    xjcVersion.set("2.3.3")
    outputJavaDir = file("${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb")
    
    ext.downloaded = file("$buildDir/xjc/downloaded/schema2.wsdl")
    doFirst {
        mkdir downloaded.parentFile
        downloaded.text = new URL("http://www.example.com/foo.xsd").text}
    
    groups {
        register("schema1") {
            xsdFiles = files(xsdDir.file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/schema1.wsdl"))
            defaultPackage.set("pl.com.project.schema1")
        }
        register("schema2") {
            xsdFiles = files(downloaded)
            defaultPackage.set("pl.com.project.schema2")
        }
    }
}
```

And I got an error in line "xjc {" :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous attempt I incorrectly assumed that xjc was a task. After looking at the [github page](https://github.com/bjornvester/xjc-gradle-plugin) I can see that "xjc" is an extension object, not a task

So try this:

```
tasks.register('downloadXsd') {
   ext.xsd = file("$buildDir/downloadXsd/foo.xsd")
   outputs.file xsd // important!!! configures the task outputs
   doLast {
      mkdir xsd.parentFile
      xsd.text = new URL("http://www.example.com/foo.xsd").text
   }
}
xjc {
    ...
    groups {
        register("schema1") {
            // assuming the plugin is written properly, this should configure a task dependency
            xsdFiles = files(tasks.named('downloadXsd'))
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

You could improve this using the [download task](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task) to download the xsd which shows progress of the download and also has caching options

Comment: Could you check my edited post? I used your solution and i got an error :)

Comment: Updated (I incorrectly assumed xjc was a task)